# Перенос функций из JS в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, функции

Есть функции, написанные на JS:

```
function DateTimeToUnix(d)
{
  var r = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 00, 00, 00));
  var n = (r.getTime()/1000); 
  return n;
}

function rezerveNCd(code)
{
  var str = rezerveCd(code);
  var c = 0;
  var char = "";
  var i = 1;
  var result = "";
  var s = "";
  for (i=0;i<str.length-1;i++)
  {
    char = str.charAt(i);
    c = char * (i+1);   
    char = c;  
    s = char.toString();

    s = s.charAt(s.length-1);


    result = result + s;
  }
  return result;
}    

function rezerveCd(code)
{
  var d = new Date()
  var unixtime = DateTimeToUnix(d);
  var i = 0;
  var str = unixtime.toString();
  var n = 1;

  code = code + 127;

  var result = str;

  for (i=0;i<=str.length-1;i++)
  {
    n = str.charAt(i)*code;
    result = result+n;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Пытаюсь написать тоже самое на PHP:

```
function mkTimestamp($year,$month,$day, $hours=00,$minutes=00,$seconds=00){
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  return mktime($hours,$minutes,$seconds, $month,$day,$year);
}

function char_at($str, $pos)
{
  return $str{$pos};
}

function rezerveCd($code) 
{
    $d = mkTimestamp(date("Y"), date("m"), date("d"));
    $i = 0;
    $stre = (string)$d;
    $n = 1;

    $code = $code + 127;
    $result = $stre;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($stre) - 1;$i++) 
    {
        $n = char_at($stre, $i) * $code;
        $result = $result + $n;
    }

    return $result;
}


function rezerveNCd($code) 
{
    $stre = rezerveCd($code);
    $c = 0;
    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($stre) - 1; $i++) 
    {
        $char = char_at($stre, $i);
        $c = $char * ($i + 1);
        $char = $c; 
        $s = (string)$char;

        $s = char_at($s, (count($s) - 1));

        $result = $result + $s;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

При вызове на JS `console.log(rezerveCd(60))` и `console.log(rezerveNCd(60))` значения выдаёт корректно
При попытке `echo rezerveCd(60);` выдаёт неполное значение, а `echo rezerveNCd(60);` ничего не выдаёт. В чём может быть проблема? Буду благодарен за помощь!
P.S. значение `console.log(rezerveCd(60)) - 15294528001899453781701756945378151200`
значение `echo rezerveCd(60); - 1529452987`

Comment: проблема в том что вы вместо того что бы продебажить самостоятельно свой код, сразу пишете сюда, что бы кто-то это сделал за вас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы путаете конкатенацию в js со сложением в php.

Почти дословный перевод:

```
function rezerveCd($code)
{
  $str = strval(time());
  $code += 127;
  $result = $str;
  for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
  {
    $n = $str{$i}*$code;
    $result .= $n;
  }
  return $result;
}

echo rezerveCd(60); // 152948781718793537416837481496130914961871309
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, еще раз почитал и допёр, спасибо за помощь!